# SQL Merge Update gives Subquery returned more than 1 value Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a stored procedure where I use Merge statement. 
And When I try to execute this sp it gives following error.

```
Msg 6401, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AnnualBudgetExcelUpload_I_U, Line 66
Cannot roll back Tran1. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AnnualBudgetExcelUpload_I_U, Line 79
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure AnnualBudgetExcelUpload_I_U, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.
Msg 3998, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.
```

I think the problem is is Merge's update statement. Since if I try this with One record or a new Record which is not available it works..

Here is my sp

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [AnnualBudgetTransaction]

BEGIN TRY

MERGE [dbo].[AnnualBudget] AS ab
USING @AnnualBudgetLines  AS bl
ON bl.Year = ab.Year 
AND ab.BudgetBreakdownId = bl.BudgetBreakdownId 
AND  ab.BudgetTypeId = bl.BudgetTypeId 
AND  ab.DepartmentSectionId = bl.DepartmentSectionId
AND  ab.BudgetCategoryId = bl.BudgetCategoryId
AND  ab.StatusId = 1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET ab.Value = ab.Value + bl.Value

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT ([Year]
           ,[BudgetBreakdownId]
           ,[FromDate]
           ,[ToDate]
           ,[BudgetTypeId]
           ,[DepartmentSectionId]
           ,[BudgetCategoryId]
           ,[Value]
           ,[AdjustmentValue]
           ,[StatusId]
           ,[CreatedUserId]
           ,[CreatedDate]
           ,[ModifiedUserId]
           ,[ModifiedDate]
           ,[Remark])
     VALUES
           (bl.Year
           ,bl.BudgetBreakdownId
           ,bl.FromDate
           ,bl.ToDate
           ,bl.BudgetTypeId
           ,bl.DepartmentSectionId
           ,bl.BudgetCategoryId
           ,bl.Value
           ,bl.AdjustmentValue
           ,bl.StatusId
           ,bl.CreatedUserId
           ,GETDATE()
           ,bl.ModifiedUserId
           ,GETDATE()
           ,NULL);

COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]
   DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

    SELECT   
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error  
    -- information about the original error that caused  
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.  
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.  
               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.  
               @ErrorState -- State.  
               );  
END CATCH
```

And the testing script I use to execute my sp
(with a single row it works)

```
DECLARE @AnnualBudgetLines AS [dbo].[AnnualBudgetList]
--INSERT INTO @Plants VALUES(2,'')
INSERT INTO @AnnualBudgetLines VALUES(117,27,2,2017,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM','1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM',2,1000,0,1,3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM',3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM')
INSERT INTO @AnnualBudgetLines VALUES(117,27,3,2017,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM','1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM',2,1000,0,1,3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM',3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM')
--INSERT INTO @Plants VALUES(117,27,4,2017,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM','1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM',2,1000,0,1,3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM',3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM')
--INSERT INTO @Plants VALUES(117,27,5,2017,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM','1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM',2,1000,0,1,3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM',3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM')
--INSERT INTO @Plants VALUES(117,27,6,2017,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM','1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM',2,1000,0,1,3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM',3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM')
--INSERT INTO @Plants VALUES(117,27,16,2017,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM','1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM',2,555,0,1,3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM',3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM')
--INSERT INTO @Plants VALUES(117,27,17,2017,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM','1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM',2,666,0,1,3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM',3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM')
--INSERT INTO @AnnualBudgetLines VALUES(117,27,18,2017,'1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM','1/31/2017 12:00:00 AM',2,777,0,1,3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM',3430,'3/10/2017 11:58:12 AM')

EXEC [dbo].[AnnualBudgetExcelUpload_I_U]  @AnnualBudgetLines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. And its not the stored Procedure or the Merge Statement.
I've written the following trigger to keep history of the data of the table and that trigger caused the problem.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_AnnualBudgetRivision]
   ON  [dbo].[AnnualBudget]
   AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     DECLARE @MaxId AS INT
        SELECT  @MaxId = MAX(dbo.AnnualBudgetVersion.VersionNo)
        FROM dbo.AnnualBudgetVersion  
        WHERE 
        dbo.AnnualBudgetVersion.AnnualBudgetId = (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)

        IF(@MAXId IS NULL )
        BEGIN
            SET @MAXId = 0;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
          SET @MAXId = @MAXId +1;
        END

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[AnnualBudgetVersion]
        SELECT *,@MAXId
        FROM DELETED;


END
```